# VBA Range.Formula with Row()

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run the following code in VBA for Excel, I get a "sub or function not defined" related to the `ROW()` function in the formula. In this instance, `rng` is

```
    rng.Formula = "=INDIRECT(""J" & Row() & """,TRUE)"
```

Is there a way that the code can be changed so that the formula can be dependent on the row that it is located in? Or is the `row()` function just a no-go for this kind of thing? What would be the alternative?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need using of Excel formula `Row()` meaning, or to use the a specific row, defined in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a string using the row number of `rng`
Say in **A3** we want to deposit:

```
=INDIRECT(J3,TRUE)
```

try:

```
Sub cbass()
    Dim rng As Range, roww As Long, stryng As String
    Set rng = Range("A3")
    
    roww = rng.Row
    stryng = "=INDIRECT(J" & roww & ",TRUE)"
    
    MsgBox stryng
    rng.Formula = stryng
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your formula `ROW()` needs to be within the quotes, otherwise it will try to handle it as VBA code but not as formula:

```
rng.Formula = "=INDIRECT(""J"" & ROW(),TRUE)"
```

But are you sure you want to use `INDIRECT`? You probably get the same result when using

```
rng.Formula = "=J" & rng.Row
```

but without the overhead of the volatile `INDIRECT`. Avoid using volatile functions, they come with a huge calculation overhead especially when used extensively.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the Excel formula `Row()` you can do it in this way:

```
rng.Formula = "=INDIRECT(""J"" & row())"
```

This will return the value from J & the row where the formula is placed.

If needing a specific row defined in vba, please use the @PEH suggestion. He maybe better understood what you try doing...